# Using Color Structure Descriptor

Tags: image-processing, colors, mpeg

According to Colour Structure Descriptor (CSD) definition it says, CSD can be use to express the structure of colours in an image using HMMD colour space. But how? 
Since it gives number of times a colour appear, how can we derive the position from it?

If it is impossible, what could I do to extract the structure of colours in an image.

(Basically I want an output to express some thing similar. **Example**: Blue on top part, Green on middle part and Brown on bottom part.)

Comment: This is NOT a [Freecode.com](http://freecode.com/): [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I think you didn't get the idea yet. I just want an idea on how to derive the structure of colours with in an image from CSD. I have gone through many papers, which explains CSD, but non of them explaining this part, Thanks

Comment: CSD is used to compute local information which then forms a histogram,  so it doesn't care about the positions of the information extracted locally (and the word structure doesn't imply that either). If you want this question to make more sense, include some references that do what you are after.